# Not able to use --testnet flag on geth windows

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

I have a problem where if put

```
geth --testnet removedb
```

it says

```
flag provided but not defined: -testnet
```

Im on windows 10 x64. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do --goerli. you cant just do --testnet!

Comment: There are several predefined test networks: ropsten, goerli, rinkeby. See other options in the document https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options.